# Is it possible to have local database file used by Electron Framework?

Tags: node.js, electron, desktop-application, local-database

i am trying to build simple desktop application using Electron Framework. I have created database using MySql Workbench and now im stuck actually connecting it. I want it to be able to run locally, offline, which means each instance of application will have its own database file with its data.

I have already done something similar using C# and .mdf file type for its database, but i cant make a similar thing using Electron.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can easily create and use a local database in an Electron app using an npm package like [`node-sqlite3`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3)